# How can I see the list of connected players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to see a list of connected players in Minecraft SMP? I tried opening chat and casting `/list` but nothing happened. Do you have to be op to do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, then you will see who is online on the server. To change the button binding for this, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and go to Controls.

Comment: True. Of course when this question was posted this feature wasn't available.

Comment: Playing on a Mac, this option doesn't work.

Comment: @Yawus actually it does for me

Answer (score 14):

This command is only available to ops. Only commands `/kill`, `/me` and `/tell` can be executed by non-ops.

Comment: Also, some plugins will have their own personalized commands to tell you who's online. If there's plugins in a server, the command /help should give you a list of what commands you can use, one of those is usually the "who's online" command.

Comment: that is true, but he is referring to smp. which is technically vanilla minecraft, and he didnt include tags like bukkit etc

Answer (score 3):

I run a bukkit server and I let the players use the `/list` command.  Even though you can push <kbd>tab</kbd> its nice to have a number and list of names right there in your chat box.

You can regulate the commands a player can use depending on the command plugin you use.  I use the Essentials command pack.

Comment: It's also the only option if you're on the server console

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the key in the options menu:

<kbd>ESC</kbd> > Options > Controls > List Players

Windows: Bind it to <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Mac: Bind it to <kbd>CMD</kbd>.